# Model.get_model_path(model_name="model") throws an error: Model not found in cache or in root at

Tags: python, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a Model that I registered it with a pipeline :

```
register_step = PythonScriptStep(name = "Register Model",
                                source_directory = training_folder,
                                script_name = "register_model.py",
                                arguments = ['--model_folder', model_folder],
                                inputs=[model_folder],
                                compute_target = pipeline_cluster,
                                runconfig = pipeline_run_config,
                                allow_reuse = True)
```

And here is my register_model.py:

```
import argparse
import joblib
from azureml.core import Workspace, Model, Run

# Get parameters
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--model_folder', type=str, dest='model_folder', default="model", help='model location')
args = parser.parse_args()
model_folder = args.model_folder

# Get the experiment run context
run = Run.get_context()

# Load the model
print("Loading model from " + model_folder)
model_file = model_folder + "/model.pkl"
model = joblib.load(model_file)

Model.register(workspace=run.experiment.workspace,
               model_path = model_file,
               model_name = 'model',
               tags={'Training context':'Pipeline'})

run.complete()
```

I can see the model is registered when i loop the existing models using the following:

```
from azureml.core import Model

for model in Model.list(ws):
    print(model.name, 'version:', model.version)
    for tag_name in model.tags:
        tag = model.tags[tag_name]
        print ('\t',tag_name, ':', tag)
    for prop_name in model.properties:
        prop = model.properties[prop_name]
        print ('\t',prop_name, ':', prop)
    print('\n')
```

However when i try to load the model in my Score.py (below) to deploy the model as a servcie, I get the following error:

I believe this is where the error coming from :

```
model_path = Model.get_model_path(
        model_name="model", version=1)
```

Error:

```
ModelNotFoundException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py in get_model_path(model_name, version, _workspace)
    751             try:
--> 752                 return Model._get_model_path_local(model_name, version)
    753             except ModelNotFoundException as ee:

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py in _get_model_path_local(model_name, version)
    783         if not os.path.exists(candidate_model_path):
--> 784             return Model._get_model_path_local_from_root(model_name)
    785         else:

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py in _get_model_path_local_from_root(model_name)
    826         raise ModelNotFoundException("Model not found in cache or in root at ./{}. For more info,"
--> 827                                      "set logging level to DEBUG.".format(candidate_model_path))
    828 

ModelNotFoundException: ModelNotFoundException:
    Message: Model not found in cache or in root at ./model. For more info,set logging level to DEBUG.
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Model not found in cache or in root at ./model. For more info,set logging level to DEBUG."
    }
}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebserviceException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-27e8df94d66f> in <module>
      1 model_path = Model.get_model_path(
----> 2         model_name="model", version=1)

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py in get_model_path(model_name, version, _workspace)
    756                     module_logger.debug("Getting model from remote")
    757                     return Model._get_model_path_remote(model_name, version, active_workspace)
--> 758                 raise WebserviceException(ee.message, logger=module_logger)
    759         else:
    760             if active_workspace is not None:

WebserviceException: WebserviceException:
    Message: Model not found in cache or in root at ./model. For more info,set logging level to DEBUG.
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Model not found in cache or in root at ./model. For more info,set logging level to DEBUG."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#Assume model_name is the variable containing name of your model
model_name = 'model'
ws = Run.get_context().experiment.workspace
model_obj = Model(ws, model_name )
model_path = model_obj.download(exist_ok = True)
model = joblib.load(model_path)
```

Comment: Please provide more description, and also a link to the documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: if i understand that correct, there's no way to get a direct access in notebooks to the model created by running an experiment. You would have to download it locally and then load it to make inferences. right ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the workspace object as below

```
Model.get_model_path(model_name = 'model', version=1, _workspace=ws)
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry about this trouble. I'm not sure what's going on in your specific case, but can you try using AZUREML_MODEL_DIR in the meantime? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-advanced-entry-script#load-registered-models