# can you download azureml models registred in a workspace to a local folder?

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I want to download all model pickle files which are registered in azureml workspace to a local folder. is this possible? using python only don't want to manually download each pickle file using ui

Comment: Can you please add more details about the SDK version that you are using?

Comment: @Ram-msft using azureml-sdk 1.47.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you retrieve your model from your workspace you  can do the following

```
model.download(exist_ok=True)
```

This is shown in the docs- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-model-model-download

This answer form @Ninja_coder for this question might be helpful- [Model.get_model_path(model_name="model") throws an error: Model not found in cache or in root at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841319/model-get-model-pathmodel-name-model-throws-an-error-model-not-found-in-cac)